# How to save Folder Names + My own Predefined Value in a > .txt file via Batch | CMD

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to upload a bunch of .7z files to my Server where my customers can get automatic download links. Once I upload the .7z files, I need to copy/paste the last file extension in a .txt editor and parse it with my website's custom URL. It's something like this:

---

**{.7z Files}**

**001187238.7z**

**009181905.7z**

---

**{Server/Link Folder}**

**https://website/s1/2291817181/918291918/**

**https://website/s1/8817530194/114532001/**

---

**{Download Links / Finished Process}**

**https://website/s1/2291817181/918291918/009181905.7z**

**https://website/s1/8817530194/114532001/001187238.7z**

---

Is there any way where I can run

```
dir /B %userprofile%\Desktop\folder > --foldernames--.txt
```

and maybe combine it with a fixed string/link:

```
https://website/s1/2291817181/918291918/
```

So, that in the end I get a link + the folder name combined, and saved inside the .txt file?

Thank you!

Comment: That's a fixed server link, and I'm only going to parse the "https://website.com/xxx | 12345.7z together. It's for a Third Party web shop, where I can add those links as "items"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm struggling to understand what you want from your description (especially, how to determine, which file should be connected to which folder), but to answer the question itself:

```
@echo off
(for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /B %userprofile%\Desktop\folder\*.7z') do (
  echo https://website/s1/2291817181/918291918/%%a
)) > --foldernames--.txt
```

Comment: You need more reputation to up- or downvote, but if it solves your problem you can accept it (click on the checkmark) and so remove your question from the "unanswered" queue. If you need more help with this issue, please adapt your question accordingly.